# How to Create own admin module in Joomla 3.x.

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

I have created a new folder in joomla/ and than paste all the files and folders of administrator folder within this.

Then i got an error message:
**Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_APPLICATION_LOAD**

How to i procees further...

Comment: Your question is really unclear. WHat do you mean by "admin module"? A module in Joomla has a specific meaning, and from what I can tell it is not what you mean.  WHat exactly is it that you are attempting to do?

Comment: Seems like you DB is not completely imported or some tables are missing.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you did with the copying and pasting, but Joomla extensions (in your case a module) are supposed to be **installed**. Please read the documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/Installing_an_extension

Answer (score 0):

You should create a folder joomla, **paste all the extracted files** of *joomla zip* into that folder and then try installing joomla using url.

Comment: Thus is the general method for joomal installation.

Comment: But I want own module (with hard code) where I have all  change permission by this module.

Comment: You need to actually explain what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you only copy/paste administrator files, is it true? (if I understand your question well) if so then you should copy all the files, not only administrator files. Then make changes in `configuration.php` for database name and host detail etc... then you will able to use joomla normally.

Note: if there is installation folder then you will prompt for installation of joomla else you will use it normally.

Also make sure your directory has read and execute permissions.

Comment: No,  I want  own administration panel where  I can change all the permission and site changes..as a user module.

Comment: What do you mean by "user module"?

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the administrator application to a folder and try to run it you need to understand that the administrator application bootstrap is assuming that the application is one level down, in the `/administrator` folder.  So all the includes that call the libraries and all the path constants are looking one level up and in many cases will have the folder name hard coded as `administrator.`  So you would need to go look at the `defines.php` and probably everything in the the `includes` folder and check for hard coding.   It should not be hard since it is just a couple of changes to put all of your files above the web root.
That said if I were making my own standalone application for administering I would not start by copying the core. I would start from scratch so you can not include all the unnecessary parts plus use the more modern parts of the framework unlike the legacy parts currently used.